# Remove previously created HTML elements when the page shows again

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onload, removeclass

I am using Liferay portlets. I have n pop up which is invoked on click of a link in a portlet. I need to dynamically create elements using Javascript based on what the user wants to add. I create `ul` once. Every subsequent time, `li` needs to be added to the same `ul`. Hence, I use `document.getElementId()` to retrieve the `ul` if already created and add items to it.

**Issue**: the problem is when I either submit the form or close the pop up and open it again, the same element created previously still exists but is hidden. Hence, when I get element by id, I can retreive the old `ul` with old values. I need this to be removed either when the pop up is submitted or closed. Or better, when the page pop up is loaded each time. Which global eventhandler do I use to remove this `ul` element? I tried `window.onload`. Does not work!

Answer (score 0):

You should just re-create the form every time a fresh form is needed.

Also, don't get Elements by ID. This is a slow DOM operation and can fail. IDs are recommended for static HTML, so CSS and Javascript can be pointed to it.

Instead of getElementsByID, just keep a reference to it in your Javascript code if you need it at all. (I assume you need it to extract the form data on submission).

A trivial example (I'm sorry for using jquery here, but it's a lingua franca anyway):

```
var inputs = { givenname: $('<input type="text">')
             , surname: $('<input type="text">')
             , age: $('<input type="select">')
             , gender: $('<select>')
                 .append($('<option>').text('Female').val(0))
                 .append($('<option>').text('Male').val(1))
                 .append($('<option>').text('Other').val(2))
             }

var form = $('<div class="myform">');
Object.keys(inputs).forEach(function(k) {
    form.append(inputs[k]);
});

function getdata() {
    var o = {}
    Object.keys(inputs).forEach(function(k) {
        o.k = inputs[k].val();
    });
    return o;
}

popupFunction(form, getdata);
```

The (to be created) function `popupFunction` can then just move the form somewhere (`mycontainer.append(form)`), and when the data should be submitted, extract the data using the getdata function.

Note the references I've spoken of are held in the `inputs` object. They're not direct DOM node references, but references to jquery objects, which in turn hold the DOM nodes, whose value can be extracted with the jquery `val()` function.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to recreate a fresh form? An example would help. New to this. Thanks :)

Comment: Under the hood, you use the Javascript DOM functions like `document.createElement`, `document.createTextNode`, `.setAttribute` and so on. It's convenient to use a toolkit like jquery to create DOM trees from Javascript. You can also write your own minimalist one in 100 lines or so, but Jquery is a good place to start and get ideas.

Comment: I've added a trivial example. It's not a nice abstraction, but ok for simple uses.

Comment: Thanks but is there any event I can put the remove function in? That would be very helpful.

Comment: There are plenty of events. You have to remove it when you don't want to display it anymore. For instance, call it when the form was successfully sent (for instance, with a condition inside the `onload` callback to XMLHttpRequest).